# Inconsistent return value Pylint

Tags: python, pylint

I have used pylint to check my code and I am receiving the following suggestion.
'Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. (inconsistent-return-statements)'. The code block is below. I am passing in a value and need to return which value range it belongs to. If I move the return value outside of the if it will return the incorrect count value. Any suggestions?

```
def findRangeValue(ranges, number):

    count = -1
    n = 2
    for x in range(len(ranges)-n+1):
        count += 1
        batch = range[x:x + n]
        if batch[0] < number <= batch[1]:
            return count
```

Comment: Two solutions: 1. Move return outside but do `break` inside instead. 2. return or raise an error after the loop (in some case that the loop goes through but you haven't returned yet.

Comment: Solution 1 works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

- You need confirm the function always have a non-empty (not `None`) return value in most common situation.
- Your code will return `None` when all if statement in the loop failed, need add a final return value outside loop.

#### example code:

```
def findRangeValue(ranges, number):
    count = -1
    n = 2
    for x in range(len(ranges)-n+1):
        count += 1
        batch = ranges[x:x + n]
        if batch[0] < number <= batch[1]:
            return count
    return -1

print(findRangeValue([1,3,5,7,9], 4))
print(findRangeValue([1,3,5,7,9], 10))
```

#### result:

```
1
-1
```

Comment: When I call the function I have implemented an if statement to check that the value returned in not None and that any values added are not more than ranges[-1]

Answer (score 1):

Your function is written in a way, that it returns a value only if a condition is met i.e .

```
if batch[0] < number <= batch[1]:
```

Assume a situation you are consuming the function something like

```
range_val = findRangeValue([1,2,3], 3)
```

If the condition was met the return value will be assigned to `range_val`. But if the condition was not met, then the function returns nothing and your `range_val` becomes `None`.

But your code expects it to be a number and not `None`. So, now you need to check the return value to avoid errors - an extra line of code.

Assume you are calling this function from various parts of your code, every where you need to bring in this check - more and more code.

To avoid this, a standard to follow is that, a function always returns what was promised. If it was not able to do so, raise an Exception so that, the caller is notified without an additional check.

In your particular scenario, you can use a `break` statement and always return a count outside (beware, if break was not met, the value could be not what you expect) Or use an additional flag variable with break, and raise an error if the flag variable was not  set.

Comment: When I call the function I have implemented an if statement to check that the value returned in not None and that any values added are not more than ranges[-1]. Would it be better to do this by raising an exception instead at the end of this function?